# Save Word to PDF with specific layout (page size and margins) from terminal

Tags: pdf, applescript, cpu-word

So far I've been saving my Word files this way:

```
set outpath to "/Users/..."

-- This part gets rid of the grant access problem
set sd to path to startup disk
tell application id "com.microsoft.Word"
    try
        close sd
    end try
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
end tell

--Saving word Document to PDF
tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "a" using command down
    tell application process "Microsoft Word"
        click menu item "Page Setup..." of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        delay 0.8
        click pop up button 2 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Page Setup"
        keystroke "custom" -- name of my custom page
        delay 0.2
        keystroke return
        delay 0.2
        keystroke return
        delay 0.2
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set activeDoc to active document
    save as activeDoc file name outpath file format format PDF
end tell
```

Problem is this code breaks with every MacOS update. Is there any way to do this from the terminal with bash?

Comment: if you vote for closing at least say why. There are flags for these topics for a reason...

Comment: Haven't VTC (yet), but how is the a `bash` question? You're obviously using applescript (and have tagged it as such). Is that code in a script file? Running from bash doesn't really affect its ability to break down w a new MacOS version (-;! . Maybe reposst to [apple.se]  (after deleting here). Good luck.

Comment: Could you tell us what OS you're using? It might be helpful given that your script breaks with every release. Version of Word, as well. And what do those clicks and keystrokes and returns do in your script?